# Issues with ardour and jackd

Tags: debian, audio, jack

I'm trying to play with ardour. When I started it up, it complained that jackd isn't running, so I ran `jackd -d alsa`, which displayed:

```
jackdmp 1.9.6
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2010 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
Using ALSA driver HDA-Intel running on card 0 - HDA Intel at 0xfc320000 irq 44
configuring for 48000Hz, period = 1024 frames (21.3 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
```

It seems this didn't help much because running `ardour2` displayed the following:

```
WARNING: Your system has a limit for maximum amount of locked memory!
         This might cause Ardour to run out of memory before your system runs
         out of memory. You can view the memory limit with 'ulimit -l', and it
         is normally controlled by /etc/security/limits.conf

Ardour 2.8.11
   (built using 7387 and GCC version 4.4.5)
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Paul Davis
Some portions Copyright (C) Steve Harris, Ari Johnson, Brett Viren, Joel Baker

Ardour comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it 
under certain conditions; see the source for copying conditions.
loading default ui configuration file /etc/ardour2/ardour2_ui_default.conf
loading user ui configuration file /home/wena/.ardour2/ardour2_ui.conf
Loading ui configuration file /etc/ardour2/ardour2_ui_dark.rc
theme_init() called from internal clearlooks engine
ardour: [INFO]: Ardour will be limited to 1024 open files
loading system configuration file /etc/ardour2/ardour_system.rc
ardour: [INFO]: No H/W specific optimizations in use
librdf warning - Model does not support contexts
librdf warning - Model does not support contexts
librdf warning - Model does not support contexts
ardour: [INFO]: looking for control protocols in /home/wena/.ardour2/surfaces/:/usr/lib/ardour2/surfaces/
ardour: [INFO]: Control protocol Tranzport not usable
ardour: [INFO]: Control surface protocol discovered: "Mackie"
ardour: [INFO]: Control surface protocol discovered: "Generic MIDI"
powermate: Opening of powermate failed - No such file or directory
ardour: [INFO]: Control protocol powermate not usable
Cannot connect to server socket err = Connection refused
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

[**note**] These are native Debian packages.

Comment: When you've started `jackd`, can you play sound with `mplayer -ao jack`? Do you have another sound server running (`esd`, `pulseaudio`, …)?

Comment: @gilles I get a similar message, `jack server is not running or cannot be started`.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing `jack`? Confirm it is running with `ps -ef | grep jack`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A snippet from the Debian-specific README file for **`ardour`** (located at "**/usr/share/doc/ardour/README.Debian**"):

> You have to run jackd and ardour as the same user.

That is, I assumed I was supposed to start **`jackd`** as root.